# Heartbleed self-test for mailserver

Tags: email-server, heartbleed

The internet is now inundated by sites like this:

- https://ssl-tools.net/heartbleed-test

Which is great, but these then immediately publish the vulnerable domains.  I have a number of private mailservers which *may* need to be rebuilt -- they were statically linked to the open ssl library, but I think perhaps a version prior to 1.0.1.  I'd like to be able to check *privately* myself which ones are vulnerable, and I'm sure there are methods to do so, but online searches now bury these results underneath a lot of chaff and the  public web tools like the one listed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this perl script to check it: https://github.com/noxxi/p5-scripts/blob/master/check-ssl-heartbleed.pl

Comment: Passed that and confirmed it with one of the web sites. Thx.